# In $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ all norms are equivalent

Tags: normed-spaces, equivalence-relations

While trying to prove the Theorem mentioned in the Title, I got stuck in the inequality shown below.

[image]

I think that the proof uses the $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ definition of continuity but I am not able to understand the steps in between the inequality.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: $\rho(x-y) = \rho(\sum_{i=1}^n(\xi_i - \eta_i)e_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n\rho((\xi_i - \eta_i)e_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n|\xi_i - \eta_i|\rho(e_i)$

Comment: @Mitscaype Do you remember what book you got this statement from? This is exactly what I need to cite, but I can't for the life of me find the statement in any of my books....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first inequality is the triangle inequality (subadditivity):

$$
\rho(x) = \rho(x - y + y) \leq \rho(x - y) + \rho(y).
$$

You can similarly show

$$
\rho(y) \leq \rho(x - y) + \rho(x)
$$

establishing the absolute values.

For the second inequality, we write

$$
x = \sum\xi_i e_i, \quad y = \sum\eta_i e_i
$$

so

$$
x - y = \sum (\xi_i - \eta_i) e_i
$$

and once again use the triangle inequality, along with homogeneity of norms (i.e. $\rho(cx) = |c|\rho(x)$ for a scalar $c$ and vector $x$).

You might think of the proof as using the limit definition of continuity (if $y \to x$, then the rightmost expression becomes very small, so the leftmost expression has to get smaller as well, showing $\rho(y) \to \rho(x)$), but of course this is equivalent to the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition, so you could easily (and correctly) think of it that way too.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers! I found @BaronVT's answer more detailed and this is what I needed. Thanks you again for your time!