# Ratio limit of volumes

Tags: measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a $C^{1}$ function defined on an open subset $U\subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$. Prove that if $f'(a)$ is not an isomorphism then 
$$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{\mathrm{vol}~ f(\bar{B}_{r}(a))}{\mathrm{vol}~\bar{B}_{r}(a)}=0.$$

It seems to be necessary to use Sard theorem, but I was not able to do it. I appreciate any help.

Edit: Since $f'(a)$ is a linear transformation which is not an isomorphism, $f'(\bar{B}_{r}(a))$ is contained in $\mathrm{Im}~ f'(a)$, which is an hipersurface of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ such it dimension is smaller than $m$.   Therefore, $f'(\bar{B}_{r}(a))$ has empty interior and thus, $\mathrm{vol}~ f'(\bar{B}_{r}(a))= 0$. Does this imply the thesis?

Comment: please, consider accepting the answer of Matheus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will demonstrate considering $B(a,r) = \{ x\in \mathbb{R}^{m};$ [$|x-a|_1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) $< r\}$ (this isn't a problem because [in $\mathbb{R}^m$ all the norms are equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026460/in-mathbbrn-all-norms-are-equivalent), realize that now $\text{Vol}(B_r(a)) = 2^m r^m $) moreover, suppose without loss of generality that $f(a) = 0$. And consider $\delta >0$ as a real number such that $\overline{B_\delta} (a) \subset U$.

Given $\varepsilon>0$, let $0<r<\delta$ be a real number sufficiently close to zero satisfying

$$\left|Df(a)(y-a) - f(y) - f(a) \right| < \varepsilon |y-a| \leq \varepsilon r$$

for all $y$ $\in$ $B_r:=\overline{B_r}(a)$.

By hypothesis $Df(a)$ isn't an isomorphism, then the set $\{Df(a)(y-a); y \in B_r \}$ lies in a $(m-1)$-dimentional subspace $V\subset \mathbb{R}^n $, consequently the set $\{f(y) - f(a); y\in B_r\}$ lies within $\varepsilon r$ of the $(m-1)$-plane $V+f(a) = V$.

On the other hand, using the compactness of $\overline{B_\delta}(a)$ and the mean value inequality, there is $M$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$, such that

$$|f(y)|=|f(y) - f(a)| < M |y-a|, \hspace{0.2cm}\forall\ y\in B_\delta(a),$$

$$\Rightarrow |f(y)|=|f(y) - f(a)| < M |y-a| \leq Mr, \hspace{0.2cm} \forall\ y\in B_r(a),\ \mbox{and }\forall\ 0<r<\delta.$$

Thus, if we change the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$, $\{e_1,...,e_m\}$, to an orthonormal basis $\{v_1,...,v_{m-1}, w\}$, where $\{v_1,...,v_{m-1}\}$ is a basis of the vector space $V$, and $w$ is normal unit vector to $V$.

Then we can consider $\mathbb{R}^m = \text{span}(v_1) \times ...\times\text{span}(v_{m-1})\times \text{span}(w)$, implying

$$f(B_r) \subset \left[-Mr,Mr\right]\times ... \left[-Mr,Mr\right]\times  [-r\varepsilon , r\varepsilon],$$

so

$$\text{Vol}(f(B_r)) \leq 2^m \varepsilon  M^{m-1} r^m = \varepsilon M^{m-1} \text{Vol}(B_r)$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{ \text{Vol}(f(B_r))}{\text{Vol}(B_r)} \leq \varepsilon  M^{m-1}.$$

Since $M$ is a fixed constant the result is proved, *i.e;*

$$\lim_{r\to 0 } \frac{ \text{Vol}\left(f\left(\overline{B_r}(a) \right)\right)}{\text{Vol}(\overline{B_r}(a) )} =0.$$

---

**Remark:** If $f(B_r) \subset \left[-Mr,Mr\right]\times ... \left[-Mr,Mr\right]\times  [-r\varepsilon , r\varepsilon]$ doesn't make sense to you, the correct way to write this would be

$$ f(B_r) \subset \{t\cdot v_1\ ; t\in[-Mr,Mr]\}\times...\times  \{t\cdot v_{m-1}\ ; t\in[-Mr,Mr]\}\times  \{t\cdot w\ ; t\in[-\varepsilon r,\varepsilon r]\},$$ 
since $\{v_1,...,v_{m-1},w\}$ is a ortonortonal basis is immediate that

$$\text{Vol}\left(\{t\cdot v_1\ ; t\in[-Mr,Mr]\}\times...\times  \{t\cdot v_{m-1}\ ; t\in[-Mr,Mr]\}\times  \{t\cdot w\ ; t\in[-\varepsilon r,\varepsilon r]\}\right) = 2^m M^{m-1}\varepsilon.$$